# Can I group classes in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I have found that to enable and disable buttons in JqueryMobile I have had to do the following:

```
 $("#enable-livetv").addClass("livetvclick ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-b");
 $("#disable-livetv").addClass("livetvclick ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c");
```

In Css is there a way to group up the classes that I can reuse them rather than having to paste that code all over the place?

So I am looking for :

```
$("#enable-livetv").addClass("enablebuttonstyle");
$("#disable-livetv").addClass("disablebuttonstyle");
```

Comment: This is more of a jQuery grouping than CSS grouping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
var classes_enable = "livetvclick ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-b";
var classes_disable = "livetvclick ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c";
$("#enable-livetv").addClass(classes_enable);
$("#disable-livetv").addClass(classes_disable);
```

[EDIT]

As per the OP's question, here's how to reuse the defined vars across many files.

First, create a file, let's say, `defines.js`, in `/js` folder (can be anything, really, this is just an example).

```
var classes_enable = "livetvclick ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-b";
var classes_disable = "livetvclick ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c";
```

Then, each time the defines are needed, it's enough to include the JS file in the `<head>` tag like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/defines.js"></script>
```

The variables should be reuseable now.

Comment: I am pretty new to JQuery and CSS and was not sure whether I could do some sort of grouping in CSS. If I want to reuse the variables in different <script> functions, would I have to define it in every method or is there a global area I could use?

Comment: within the same .html/.php file, you can define it once and you can reuse it any place within the same file, also in separate `<script>` tags. You can also create a separate `.js` file with your defines and include it in other files - this way you can use the same set across the entire project :).

Comment: Thanks, did not know you could do that. I have just created a plugin that has functions enablelink() and disablelink(). Is this a bit of an overkill?

Comment: Perhaps it is, I don't really know what criteria should be used to judge this :). I don't usually wrap such simple things in functions, but if you feel comfortable with this, I suppose it's fine :).

Comment: Thanks for all the help. You have given me a few options to play with.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var myClass = "livetvclick ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-b";

$("#enable-livetv").addClass(myClass);
```

perhaps ?

Comment: Same as my answer, but +1 nonetheless :P

Answer (score 1):

put thoses classes in a variable ?

```
enablebuttonstyle = "livetvclick ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-b";
disablebuttonstyle = "livetvclick ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c";

$("#enable-livetv").addClass( enablebuttonstyle );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem really is, this will reduce your codes.

```
var css = " livetvclick ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ";
$("#enable-livetv").addClass(css + "ui-btn-up-b");
$("#disable-livetv").addClass(css + "ui-btn-up-c");
```

Comment: Is it possible to reuse the above code so that I can use it in different script functions in the same page and on different pages?

Answer (score 0):

Use variable in JS (but most probably you will polute global namespace), CSS or solution like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) (but it requires some kind of compilation).
Saying CSS I mean adding your class to definitions of ui classes:

```
.ui-btn, .enablebuttonstyle {/* def*/}
.ui-btn-inline, .enablebuttonstyle {/* def*/}
.ui-btn-corner-all, .enablebuttonstyle {/* def*/}
```

Theoretically should work.

Comment: I think the OP was asking something different (or so I understood) :P

Comment: I think OP meant exactly what I wrote ;)